# Matlab datetime in Python

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I am trying to read some Matlab files with waveforms in which the timestamp was stored in Matlab datetime format (**not** datenum, for which there are several questions already).

I get the data with:

```
import scipy.io as spio
mat_data = spio.loadmat(file_path, squeeze_me=True)
```

The variables in Matlab are *t* and *data*, and in mat_data I get:

```
In[64]: mat_data
Out[64]:
{'None': MatlabOpaque([ (b't', b'MCOS', b'datetime', array([3707764736,          2,          1,          1,          1,
                 1], dtype=uint32))],
              dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')]),
 '__function_workspace__': array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8),
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri Dec 01 14:44:33 2017',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'data': array([  0.70606027,   0.70559802,   0.70583525, ...,  20.45188265,
         20.45204609,  20.4512548 ])}
```

I think the datetime data from *t* is in the keys 'None' and '**function_workspace**', but I am not capable to understand how to get the time from them.

```
mat_data['__function_workspace__'].shape
Out[65]: (1, 20736704)

mat_data['data'].shape
Out[66]: (2591959,)
```

Any idea on how to read those values?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I am sorry to say that my solution was to regenerate all the data with unix timestamp, which is universal, instead of the Matlab datetime type...